# Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.tools.JavaVersionChecker

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have installed elasticsearch in AWS RHEL server. While running elasticsearch It is throwing below exeception. I tried all the solutions but not helpful. Could any one please give me a solution for this.

```
$ /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.elasticsearch.tools.JavaVersionChecker
>       Elasticsearch requires at least Java 8 but your Java version from
>
> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java does not meet this requirement

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
`
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144
```

Answer (score 1):

Move to proper bin folder

`../elasticsearch/bin/`

if you are running elastic search on

gitbash: `./elasticsearch.bat`

windows shell: `elasticsearch.bat`

if you are not running somewhere else , find a appropriate command to run a 
 **bat** script